# Creating fake employees to market business?

Tags: business, names

I am starting anew business which involves professional serves. I though of creating fake employees names just for (receptionist, office manager) to make it look more professional and to make the company look bigger and trustworthy. These characters are not ment to sell or engage in any contracts, they just respond to emails and forward them to me personally so I take it from their. Its similar to answering initial inquiries with ( company HR team/ company team) i just wanted to use real names to make it more personal! I have no intention whatsoever to use it for any Haram or Fraud reasons.